# Lotus Notes Java plugin create a delegate meeting

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, lotus-notes

I have a code that creates a meeting on a Notes calendar.
I want to recognize if I'm in a delegate state (create a meeting on someone else calendar [and I don't know in advance who it is]).
Now my code creates it automatically on my users calendar (the user I log in with), and it looks like that -

```
NotesUIWorkspace nui = new NotesUIWorkspace();
session = NotesFactory.createSessionWithFullAccess();                                                                
DbDirectory dbdir = session.getDbDirectory(null);                                                                                                   
Database maildb = dbdir.openMailDatabase();

NotesDatabaseData dbData = new NotesDatabaseData(maildb);
NotesFormData formData = new NotesFormData (dbData, "Appointment"); 

formData.addComposeItem("SendTo", Eto); 
formData.addComposeItem("Subject", Esub); 
formData.addComposeItem("Body", Ebody); 

nui.composeDocument(formData);
```

How can I open the delegated database just by clicking on a sidebar button when the delegated calendar is open?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I found it

```
                NotesUIWorkspace nui = new NotesUIWorkspace();
                session = NotesFactory.createSessionWithFullAccess();   

                NotesUIElement elem = nui.getCurrentElement();
                NotesDatabaseData dbData = null;
                if (elem instanceof NotesUIView){
                    final NotesUIElement view = elem;
                    NotesViewData viewData = (NotesViewData) Platform.getAdapterManager().getAdapter(view, 
                            NotesViewData.class);
                    dbData = (NotesDatabaseData) Platform.getAdapterManager().getAdapter(view, 
                            NotesDatabaseData.class);

                    System.out.println(dbData.getReplicaId());
                    System.out.println(viewData.getOpenUrl());

                } 

                DbDirectory dbdir = session.getDbDirectory(null);

                if(dbData == null){
                    Database maildb = dbdir.openMailDatabase();
                    dbData = new NotesDatabaseData(maildb);
                }

                NotesFormData formData = new NotesFormData (dbData, "Appointment"); //$NON-NLS-1$

                formData.addComposeItem("Subject", Esub); //$NON-NLS-1$
                formData.addComposeItem("Body", Ebody); //$NON-NLS-1$
                //formData.addComposeItem("IWFlag", "1");  //uses LNA if configured

                nui.composeDocument(formData);
```